# Down Vote to New Users Question

Tags: discussion, questions

suppose a new user question got so many downvotes, will his reputation go to a negative value.

ie, a new user might with 10 reputation,

and got six downvotes for his question (assume that a downvote costs 2 reputation).

what will be his reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, 1 is the lowest possible reputation.

Comment: ...which doesn't mean it's fine to ask such a terrible question.

Comment: No, when _evil_ Jeff took over for a day (the one _without_ the goatee), reputation mysteriously turned into a signed integer. They just use abs() when displaying it so certain people don't feel bad ..

Answer (score 2):

Also to add if I were to have a downvote when I have 1 it will not be taken away when I get say an upvote.